# Tor Browser Bundle must be run within the X Window System. Exiting

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux, kali-linux

I was following the Tor installation process in Kali Linux. When I attempted to run the `./start-tor-browser` command while logged in as root, which is the default in Kali Linux, it did not work. So I added an user using the following command:

```
adduser neha
```

I logged in as that user from terminal:

```
login neha
```

I went to the appropriate location:

```
cd /root/tor-browser_en-US
```

and executed the command:

```
./start-tor-browser
```

Then I got the message mentioned in the question title. What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Did you start the X window system before running the browser? The error message sounds as if you are trying to open the browser from the command line without any graphical desktop interface running. If that's the case, start the X Window from the root user:

```
startx
```

Answer (score 0):

Tor doesnt allow to be run in root user if you need to run it under root user than modify the start-tor-browser script which in kali linu is present in
 `/home/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browwser_en-US/Browser` and comment the lines

```
#if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
#   complain "The Tor Browser Bundle should not be run as root.  Exiting."
#   exit 1
#fi
```

save it and run it from command line

```
./start-tor-browser
```

Comment: The original poster made a new user and wants to run Kali Linux as this user. You're suggesting to run the application as root. This is considered bad practice and should be avoided.